# When is implementing an android.widget.Adapter better than extending an android.widget.BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm wondering when it's more appropriate to implement an `android.widget.Adapter` or `android.widget.ListAdapter`, rather than extend an android.widget.BaseAdapter. To put some context into it, I have a list that consists of different sub-classes of a `BaseMessage` class, so I figure I'll need to override `getItemViewTypeCount(int position)` and `getItemViewType(int position)`.